# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm using `Aurelia` to build a web application. I want to display a detail page passing a parameter (id) from the list view. This is my (simplified, "Detail" is basic data class) controler code:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetDetail(int _id)
    {
        var b = new Detail()
        var customjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b, Formatting.Indented);
        return Ok(customjson);
    }
```

The detail is fetched through the `activate()` method in the detail.ts class:

```
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.http = http;
}

activate(params: any) {
    this.http.fetch("api/Begroting/GetBegroting/" + params.id)
        .then(result => result.json as Promise<Begroting>)
        .then(data => {
            this.begroting = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

However when the detail page is loaded via the list page it gives this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Testing the API via Swagger yields valid json and a status code 200.

implying that there is something wrong with the API(call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP already solved his problem, but to clarify for future readers what was likely going on:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON` is an error that typically occurs when you request a non-existing resource. The server returns a standard `404` HTML error response.

The client will then fail when it tries to parse the HTML document as JSON (it's the first `<` of the `<html>` tag that it fails on).

#### The client needs a status code instead of an error page

The deeper issue here is that the server should really return a `404` *status code* response so the client knows that the request failed, and won't try to process it as if it succeeded. A 404 error html page is accompanied by a `200` status code, after all.

So besides fixing the request url on the client side (or the route on the server side), the server and/or client should be configured such that proper status codes are returned as well. I believe `Accept: application/json` takes care of this although I haven't tested that.

#### And an alternative solution for OP:

The idea behind RESTful services is that your URI's represent resources; the query string is nice for sorting/filtering/paging parameters and such on lists. An ID kind of belongs in the path, not in the query string.

Change your route attribute to: `[HttpGet("[action]/{_id}")]` and your initial client code should work again.

Answer (score 1):

We made a call to api/Begroting/GetBegroting/_id instead of specifying id as a GET parameter. The result was that the call to the api rerouted us back to index.html. Hence the unexpected token < in JSON Aurelia error.

To fix it, change the API call to api/Begroting/GetBegroting/?_id= + params.id

Comment: An answer like this is totally useless. How does it help someone else with a similar problem know what to fix?